# If $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$, then prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}g(x)$ exists and find this limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

Let $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}.$$ Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}g(x)$ exists and find this limit.

As regards the interval of convergence of the series, here is what I have done:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\Big|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\frac{n(n+1)}{x^{n}}\Big|$$
$$=|x|\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\Big|\frac{n}{n+2}\Big|=|x|$$
This implies that the series converges absolutely for values of $|x|<1$, diverges for values of $|x|>1$. When $x=1$, the series converges by Comparison test. When $x=-1$, the series converges by Alternating series test.

My question is, does this case:
**When $x=1$, the series converges by Comparison test,**
 solve my problem? If not, can anyone help me with a the proof because I got stuck at this point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ Szeto and uniquesolution, thanks for the reply. I just corrected my typo. It's $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}.$

Comment: The limit is $1$ by telescoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice $g$ is a power series and is thus uniformly convergent within the radius of convergence. With a little work we can thus show that as we approach $1$ from below we can interchange the limit and summation to get

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1^-}g(x)&=\lim_{x \to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} =\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Which is an easily evaluated, telescoping series.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Actually thought about this but was concerned about $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}.$ Hope this does not affect the solution?

Comment: @ Brevan Ellefsen: How about $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}$? I believe it does! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mike I just can't seem to manage to type this correctly tonight XD I accidentally left one of the limit typos in the last edit - I've now fixed *that one* as well. You have my apologies for all these typos.

Comment: @ Brevan Ellefsen, thanks for all!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\\ =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\\ =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{1}{x}\left(-x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\right) \\ =\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}+1=-\log(1-x)\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+1\rightarrow1, x\rightarrow1^-$$

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: You also deserve the points!

Answer (score 1):

An elementary calculation shows that for every $|x|<1$,

$$g(x)=\frac{x+\log(1-x)-x\log(1-x)}{x}$$

hence, by L'hopital's rule, $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}g(x)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, how did $g(x)$ be that? I need some clarity!

Comment: Sorry, it is Saturday and I don't work.

Comment: Thanks! Bob has elaborated your work!